# supress expansion of * in echo

Tags: mysql, shell-scripting, unix-shell, command-line-interface, echo

I am working on a script which dynamically executes some queries on daily basis. These queries are coming from a table in the database.

Here is the sample output of the query table:

```
+---------------+-------------------------------+---------+
| query_name    | query                         | userid  |
+---------------+-------------------------------+---------+
| All_User      | select * from users LIMIT 10; | jmatthe |
+---------------+-------------------------------+---------+
```

Now, I have to execute the query `select * from users LIMIT 10;` dynamically. I am reading each line of the output and storing the query from the output.

```
query_name=$(echo $query | cut -d\| -f1)
query_sql=$(echo $query | cut -d\| -f2)
query_user=$(echo $query | cut -d\| -f3)
```

Now here is where the problem arises. Because my line contains a `*` character in it, `echo $query` expands the `*` to replace it with the files in the current directory. So basically, my `query_sql` stores something like this.

```
select batchemail.sh query_output.txt from tbl_query
```

I want to preserve the `*` in the line so that I get the same in my `query_sql` variable. I want my `query_sql` variable to store the original data.

```
select * from tbl_query
```

Can anybody guide me on this?

Comment: Feel free to edit your question instead of other's answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You disable it by adding the following line in your script:

```
set -o noglob
```

As an example,

```
echo *
your files and folders are shown here..
set -o noglob
echo *
*
```

Comment: Too bad. I thought escaping the * would help me, but now the query doesn't work.

Comment: @divinedragon I don't understand your comment. What are you talking about? Does "now the query doesn't work" refer to the `set -o noglob` proposal or to something completely different which you did but didn't mind telling us...?

Comment: I thought making the query as ````select \*```` would help me and the ````*```` would not expand. But later on, the ````select \*```` query didnt run on MySQL. With your option, I was able to do that.

Answer (score 8):

You can put it into "":

```
$ ls
file1  file2  file3  file4  file5  file6  file7  file8  file9
$ Q='select * from table;'
$ echo $Q
select file1 file2 file3 file4 file5 file6 file7 file8 file9 from table;
$ echo "$Q"
select * from table;
```